Dynamically inject different object/token into a class
I need to implement some sort of strategy pattern with tsyringe but can't figure out how to dynamically inject the strategy into my context class without polluting the dependency container.
interface IThing {
  exec(): void;
}

@injectable()
class Thing1 implements IThing {
  exec(): void {
    console.log('thing 1');
  }
}

@injectable()
class Thing2 implements IThing {
  exec(): void {
    console.log('thing 2');
  }
}

@injectable()
class Test {
  constructor(
    // how would the container know which is which between Thing1 and Thing2?
    @inject('??')
    private readonly thing: IThing,
  ) {
    thing.exec();
  }
}

// find a way to resolve `Test` and give it Thing1 or Thing2

I'm unsure how I could use container.resolve(Test) and give it Thing1/Thing2.
I know I could do something like the following, but I not sure this is very elegant, as it pollutes the container and risks instantiating Test with the wrong strategy:
@injectable()
class Test {
  constructor(
    @inject('Thing')
    private readonly thing: IThing,
  ) {
    thing.exec();
  }
}

container.provide("Thing", { useClass: Thing1/2 })
const test = container.resolve(Test) // test with proper strategy, but now the container is polluted

Is there a more elegant way to implement this pattern?

I can think of 2 ways:

child-container, you could create different container scope depending your application flow
interception, you could add your specific resolving login in the beforeResolution

You could remove the @inject('Thing') on Test class.
example of option 1:
const container1 = container.createChildContainer();

container1.register(IThing, {useClass: Thing1});

const test1 = container1.resolve(Test); // output : 'Thing 1'


const container2 = container.createChildContainer();

container2.register(IThing, {useClass: Thing2});

const test2 = container2.resolve(Test); // output : 'Thing 2'


